# Showing that a Sequence Containing Indicator Functions Converges a.s.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $f_{n}(x) = n1_{[0,1/n]}(x)$, where $f_{n}$ maps R with the Borel sigma-algebra to itself. Also, let $\Omega = [0,1]$, your sigma-algebra is the Borel sets in [0,1], and $P(dx)=dx$. Show that the lim of $f_{n} = 0$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.

It makes sense intuitively, because as n gets very large, the interval [0,1/n] becomes very small. Thus, the likelihood for any x being on such a small interval will also shrink. Mathematically, though, I am unsure how to express this.

Any assistance you could provide would be most helpful and most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove that $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]\setminus \{0\}$ (since $\{0\}$ has $0$ measure this will do the job). Take $x\gt 0$. What is $f_n(x)$ for $n\geqslant 1/x+1$? This gives that for a fixed $x$, one can find an integer $N(x)$ such that $f_n(x)=0$ if $n\geqslant N(x)$, hence $f_n(x)\to 0$ for each $x\neq 0$.

Comment: 0, right? I got that far, and see that for n sufficiently large, $f_{n}(x) \to 0$. But how do I write that rigorously?